# TeX distribution and TeX implementation

Tags: distributions

TeX distributions are the large collections of TeX-related software to be downloaded and installed. For example, Tex Live and MiKTeX.

TeX implementations are [for example](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html#Top)

> Web2c is the name of a TeX implementation, originally for Unix, but
>   now also running under DOS, Amiga, and other operating systems. **By
>   TeX implementation, we mean** all of the standard programs developed
>   by the Stanford TeX project directed by Donald E. Knuth: Metafont,
>   DVItype, GFtoDVI, BibTeX, Tangle, etc., as well as TeX itself. Other
>   programs are also included: DVIcopy, written by Peter Breitenlohner,
>   MetaPost and its utilities (derived from Metafont), by John Hobby,
>   etc.

1. So I wonder what differences and relations are between Tex
   distributions and Tex implementations?
2. If Web2c is not a TeX distribution, then why?
3. What else besides Web2c are also examples of TeX implementations?

Thanks!

Comment: Web2C is a method for going from the "written program" to the compiled binaries for a specific platform: it transforms the Pascal sources into C sources which can then be compiled with a C compiler. A TeX distribution contains also all the necessary files to run various flavors of TeX (Plain, LaTeX, ConTeXt, …).

Comment: @egreg: (1) I still don't see why Web2C is not a distribution. (2) Is Web2C an engine/compiler/interpreter then?

Comment: `Web2C` is properly a set of programs that transform a WEB source (literate programs written in Pascal) to C for later compilation.

Answer (score 5):

Web2C is a method for going from the "written program" to the compiled binaries for a specific platform: it's a set of script that transform the Pascal sources (from the WEB file after applying `tangle`) into C sources which can then be compiled with a C compiler.

A TeX distribution contains also all the necessary files to run various flavors of TeX (Plain, LaTeX, ConTeXt, …): base files such as `plain.tex` or `latex.ltx`, font metric files, support files, other scripts and so on.